# How to create folder without trailing white space?

Tags: python, path, operating-system

In this code I check if a folder exists and if it doesn't I create it, but, I am creating it with a trailing white space because I can't do a `+ "\"` with the quotes right in front of the `\`. How can I add the `NewFolderPath` without this space?

```
dir_carteiras = r"C:\Users\GuilhermeMachado\Documents\Carteiras"
test = os.listdir(dir_carteiras)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".jpg"):
        os.remove( os.path.join(dir_carteiras, item))

today=datetime.date.today()
five_day=datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
d_N1=today+five_day
d_N1_ = d_N1.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

NewFolderPath = dir_carteiras+"\Historico"+"\ "+d_N1_
isFile = os.path.exists(NewFolderPath)
```

Comment: `"\\"` is a way to represent a single backslash `"\"` in Python (with no trailing space character).

Comment: Please be clear about the desired result.  The answer below doesn't do what I *think* you want.  The various uses of backslash in strings a well-documented, so I'm particularly uncertain where you have trouble getting whatever result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `os.path.join()`. It inserts the correct symbol for you.

```
NewFolderPath = os.path.join(dir_carteiras,"Historico",d_N1_)
```